# Prove that the sum of squares of a finite field sums to $0$ if $|F|\geq 4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If there is a finite field $F=\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ with $|F|\geq 4$. The prove that 
$$a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... + a_n^2 = 0$$

I have a proof but I am not sure of it.

We have that $F^* = F-\{0\}$ is a cyclic multiplicative group.

So there is a generator $a$ such that $F^*=\{a, a^2, ..., a^{n-1}\}$

If $a=1$ then $F=\{0,1\}$ which contradicts $|F|>4$ and hence we can choose $a\in F^*, a\neq 1$.

Now assume WLOG that $a_n=0$ is the zero element in the field.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i ^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^{2i} = \frac{a^2(1-a^{2(n-1)})}{1-a}=\frac{a^2(1-1)}{1-a}=0$

However, I feel I have done something here that implicitly uses the fact that $F$ has more than $3$ elements, but I don't see where I used that.

Comment: The denominator above should be $1 - a^2$, not $1 - a$. Both $1 - a^{2(n-1)}$ and $1 - a^2$ vanish for $a^2 = 1$, so the last equality doesn't hold. (The sum is just $a^2 + \cdots + a^{2(n-1)} = 1 + \cdots + 1 = n - 1$ in that case.)

Comment: Got it. And I can always find an $a^2\neq 1$ in a field if its size is more than $3$ and that's where it is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compute the partial sum of a geometric series with ratio $a^2$, so you must have $a^2 \neq 1$ in your computation, which happens iff $|F| > 3$.

Here is another proof: the polynomial $P=X^{|F|-1}-1$ vanishes at every element of $F^*$, and has degree $|F|-1$, and is monic, so is exactly the product of all $(X-a)$, $a \in F^*$. Assume that $|F| \geq 4$, then the coefficients of $P$ in front of $X^{|F|-2}$ and $X^{|F|-3}$ vanish.

Now, it is easy to check that if $Q=(X-a_1)\ldots (X-a_k)=X^k-bX^{k-1}+cX^{k-2}+\ldots$, then $a_1^2+\ldots+a_k^2=b^2-2c$.

In our case $b=c=b^2-2c=0$.

Comment: Ahh! I seem the ratio is $a^2$ and there is an element with $a^2\neq 1$ only if the size of the field is at least $4$. Got it. Nice proof by the way :)

Answer (score 4):

If $\#F > 3$, then some $\alpha\in F^\times$ has $\alpha^2 \not= 1$. But the map $x \to \alpha x$ permutes $F$, so 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x\in F} x^2 = \sum_{x\in F} (\alpha x)^2 = \alpha^2 \sum_{x\in F} x^2.
\end{align*}
The given sum must therefore vanish.